# Angular reactive forms pattern validator adding $ to regex and breaking validation

Tags: regex, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to validate a password with the following regex:
`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})`.
Note that there is no terminating `$` char, because that would prevent valid passwords from being accepted. (I'm not sure why the input field doesn't terminate the string).
However, Angular's `Validators.pattern` adds the end of string char. And therefore my valid passwords fail.
How do I prevent the pattern validator from adding the `$`?
I suppose I could roll my own password validator, but surely there is a better solution...?

EDIT:
Passwords that should succeed:

- Test1234
- tEst1234
- tesT1234
- 1234Test
- 1234tesT
- t#St1234

Passwords that should fail:

- TEST1234
- test1234
- tEst123
- Test123
- testtest
- 12345678

Validator declaration:

```
this.password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})')]);
this.userForm.addControl('Password', this.password);
```

Comment: Please give us one or two examples of what passwords you tried, and also how you declared your validator.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may add a `.*` at the end, or even revamp the pattern a bit to convert one lookahead into a consuming pattern:

```
Validators.pattern('(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}')
```

Or, better, when using a regex for password validation, follow the [principle of contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast):

```
Validators.pattern('(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9]).{8,}')
```

Angular will add `^` and `$` on both ends of the regex pattern, so the pattern will look like

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9]).{8,}$
```

Note it won't add the anchors automatically if you use a **regex literal**, add them manually:

```
Validators.pattern(/^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d).{8,}$/)
```

With a regex literal, you may use single backslashes in regex escapes (`/\d/` to match a digit vs. `"\\d"` in a string literal).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2mr6yi/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - at least 1 lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` - at least 1 ASCII digit
- `.{8,}` - any 8 or more chars (other than line break chars)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Changing the length lookahead to a consuming pattern solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Can i assign this dynamically i mean (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]) this code validates for 1 upper case letter what if i want 2 uppercase letters ?

Comment: @JigneshMistry Replace `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])`  with `(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})`

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked :) Just one more trouble can u send the regex for 2 Numeric & 2 special characters ?

Comment: @JigneshMistry They are formed the same way as above.

Comment: regex for special characters is not mentioned above

Comment: @JigneshMistry What chars do you consider special? Anyway, still, it will be formed the same way: `(?=(?:[^special_chars]*[special_chars]){2})`

Comment: ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) - all these i am considering as special characters

Comment: @JigneshMistry So, I guess there is no problem with that. `(?=(?:[^!@#$%^&*()]*[!@#$%^&*()]){2})`

Comment: Angular is throwing this error after puting special characters ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?=(?:[^!@#$%^&*()]*[!@#$%^&*()]){2})(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){1})(?:[^!-0]*[!-0]){2})(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){1}).{8,}$/: Unmatched ')'

Comment: @JigneshMistry Your pattern is corrupt. I think you wanted to write it as  [`/^(?=(?:[^!@#$%^&*()]*[!@#$%^&*()]){2})(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=(?:[^!-0]*[!-0]){2})(?=[^0-9]*[0-9]).{8,}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/S4ww0L/1)