# Why doesn't form validation work with built-in and corss-field validators?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material

I'm trying to create a form with built-in validators and cross-field validator and it's not working properly and I can't figure out why.

There are 4 types of built-in validators: **required, pattern, minLength** and **maxLength**.

- **Required** is working for all the fields.
- **Pattern** is working only for names group.

Here is some code - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvuuwm?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your regexp to something like this:

```
password = '(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9]).{5,}'
```

RegExp is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51741621/2050306

Also it is helpful to be able to see these errors during development:

```
<pre>
  {{ myForm.value | json }}
  {{ myForm.valid }}
  {{ myForm.get('passwords').get('password').errors | json }}
</pre>
```

error object keys are lowercase, change this minLength -> minlength in your TS file:

```
this.myForm.get('names.firstName').hasError('minlength') ?
```

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvuuwm-qhrzxh?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts).

Comment: Password pattern looks like it's working now but there are still minLength and maxLength which are not working. For example if I enter on firstName input a word with less than 5 letters, no message is displayed but field is turning red.

Comment: @Robert I updated my answer check the stackblitz. Generally all the places where you call get***errorMessage use lowercase keys. minLenght -> minlength etc.